# How to unpack two values at a time?

Tags: python, class, integer

So I have this input that can be as many integers as the user wants.

And I want to split them up in two's.

```
number = input()
a, b = (int(i) for i in numbers.split(' '))
Hey = Change(a, b)
```

The **Change** is just a class that does something to the a, b. My issue here is that when I run it and the user gives more than two integers, I get an error saying: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Is there a way to set this up so it unpacks the first two and then the next two and so on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
numbers = input()
tokens = numbers.split()
for a, b in zip(tokens[::2], tokens[1::2]):
    Hey = Change(int(a), int(b))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy you can do something like:

```
gen = (int(i) for i in input().split())
for a in gen:
   Hey = Change(a, next(gen))
```

Because gen is an generator expression, the for loop will take the first item, and assign it to `a`, and `next(gen)` call will get the 2nd value from the generator, so you will get both values in a pair. It's better solution because you don't need an extra copy of the list, like it's being done in the answer below.

Comment: While you're at it, you could do `gen = map(int, input().split())`.

Comment: Actualy in my opinion there is no need for using map function anymore, while the generator expressions  or dict/list comprehensions are more readable to me. However, I agree, that your answer is also good, but it's just about personal preferences.

Comment: Speed-wise they are the same.  I find `map` more readable in this case, but that's admittedly personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = '1 2 5 8 6 9 4 5'
num_list = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(' ')]
for i in num_list[::2]:
    print(i, num_list[num_list.index(i)+1])
```

out:

```
1 2
5 8
6 9
4 5
```